# Conditonally convergent series implies convergence of series of absolute values

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent sequence and $c > 1$, prove that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty
|a_n|^c$
is also convergent.

**My attempt:**

Initially, I was just working with $a_n \rightarrow 0$, but I needed to incorporate the fact that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence. So, I know, there exists some $N_0$ such that for $n \ge N_0$, we have $|a_n| \lt \epsilon < 1$
and for these $a_n(s)$, $|a_n|^c < |a_n|$

But I can't use the comparison test at this stage because I don't have that $a_n$ is absolutely convergent. How do I find a series that is convergent and bigger than $|a_n|^c$?

Comment: If $a_n$ is non-negative then convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence. Otherwise the statement is incorrect as shown in an answer below.

Comment: Do you mean convergent series rather than convergent sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true if $a_n$ is not non-negative.

Take for instance $c=2$ and $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

If $a_n$ is non-negative then you can use comparison test,thus your proof will be correct.